# Can azure function will use the Application SSO token for authentication?

Tags: azure, authentication, azure-active-directory, azure-functions

I'm working on typescript application which calls Azure function internally with URL.
I have to maintain security to this application and for the azure function also.(As this is a client based application, any one can view the Azure function URL in browser console)
Initially when we hit the application, it will ask for Sigle sign  authentication on Popup, where the user will give his/her AD credentials.
Now after login, at some time we will click the button, this will call the Azure function.

Is there any way can we use the same SSO authentication used earlier for application login will be allowed for internally used azure function ?

I'm working on creating one common app registration for both application and Azure function.
will this resolve my problem?

My requirement is
After single sign on, whenever the call goes to azure function, it should give the function output and should not ask for credentials again.

Answer (score 0):

Ideally. this is not the right way from the security point of view. Your Azure Function needs to receive the token from client app, and validate it against your identity provider (IDP), to make sure it's a valid token and issued by IDP. Then, if your Azure Functions needs to access Azure Resources, you should grant a managed identity to it, and then, grant access to this managed identity.